# Queue sub suites for execution in MTM

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I have a test plan which contains a test suite which has 4 sub suites of automated test cases. I want to execute all the subsuites one after the other without manual intervention. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try running test cases from command prompt, this requires the least manual intervention, as once all things are set you need to change only the build number to run your test cases.
refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465192.aspx)

Comment: Thank you.. but I want to run all the test cases from MTM.

Comment: In MTM a test run is created for test cases present in a particular suite hence only one suite can be run at a time. You can queue all suites one by one but not all suites at once.

Comment: yes. i w ant to queue all sub-suites within a single suite.